# what is wrong with this query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 nodes: `1` and `2`.

`1` is of type `user`. `2` is of type `plan`.

I am trying to create a relationship:

```
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1'), n2=node:node_auto_index(id='2') 
create n1-[:user_of_plan]->n2;
```

It executes but does not create the relationship. Can anyone tell why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
    start n1=node:node_auto_index('id:1'), n2=node:node_auto_index('id:2')
    with n1,n2
    create n1-[:user_of_plan]->n2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using labels, you could use the following query:

```
MATCH (u:User), (p:Plan)
CREATE u-[:user_of_plan]->p;
```

Note that this will create more than one relationship if you have more Users or Plans.